# Stack Overflow navbar redirects to stackexchange.com if clicked before the site is loaded completely

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar, global-inbox

I am using the latest version of Chrome
on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver). The [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) site seems to have a bug.

If a user is already logged in and visits [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) it redirects the user to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) if the logged-in user clicks on any of the following four links before the site is completely loaded:

1. *Recent inbox messages*
2. *Recent achievements*
3. *Help Center and other resources*
4. *A list of all 176 Stack Exchange sites*

The redirect happens only if the links are clicked ***before*** the site is fully loaded.

*Expected behavior:*  
The links should show the user how to appropriately show the notifications and inboxes in a pop box - normally like it does when the site is completely loaded, instead of redirecting to another site.

Comment: There's not really anything we can do if you're clicking things before the JavaScript has had a chance to run and add event handlers. If the scripts aren't going yet, then they just function as links.

Comment: Can't you give the links more meaningful href's? for example, the the inbox could link to the inbox in the profile, recent achievements to badges in the profile, etc, would at the least be better than sending you to a different site entirely.

Comment: @KevinB:  I think that's because the top bar is universal and exists across all sites.  Adding that logic in per site would mean you'd have to update it per site, which I recall was explicitly a decision that they wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Makoto A relative url would work universally, without changing it per site.